# what tools will help my collaboration, version control and work-flow

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow

I need a database to upload my artwork so they can be shared between myself, another designer and manufacturer. I'd like some suggestions of different services used within the designing community.

I'd like to be able to upload the file and be able to label colors. I want all info right in front of me when I pull up the file. Albeit barcode, colors, size etc.

Looking to keep things simple. Suggestions?

Comment: use mercurial, tortoisehg for gui

Comment: @joojaa what advantages would Mercurial have over another DVCS like Git? Is there anything about Mercurial that makes it better for design work?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like https://frontify.com could fit your needs. 1 Project and 10mb is on the free plan.

Comment: Thanks qudrat for mentioning us.
Andrew with [Frontify](https://www.frontify.com) you can discuss, specify and prototype your designs.
You can try it, let me know if you need assistance or more insights.

Comment: @JosipBudzaki Thanks for your input, I converted it to a comment because it was more of a comment on qudrat's answer anyway. May I ask you to tread carefully when promoting your product here? As per [our behaviour guidelines](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), please honestly disclose your affiliation in your answers and your profile. Thanks! Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

[**Uxpin**](http://www.uxpin.com/) is not free, but I've used it for sharing interface design and it's worked really well.

You can create interfaces dragging elements, it uses Smart Objects, interactions, has a huge library of elements, version control and a nice comment system. Only downside is that every person in the project needs to have an account, which is quite pricey.

Answer (score 0):

UXpin it's slow and missing features like nested groups. I use InVision, much more efficient. For version management look at PixeLapse

Comment: Hi Emidio, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!